# Sorting php/MySQL search results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I have a tutoring website with approximately 50 tutors. I'd like to split the search results into 5 pages of 10 tutors each.

The results are weighted, so they don't come out in order according to some primary key. I think this prevents me from writing a query like this for the first page:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE primary_key > 0 AND primary key < 11
```

and a query like this for the second page:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE primary_key > 11 AND primary key < 21
```

So, how can I systematically accept only 10 rows at a time, remember what they are, and then select the next ten rows for the next page? Should I have a second key that assigns a numeric order to the results after calculating their weights? Could this be a temporarily column? Is this a poor way to split up results in an PHP/MySQL environment?

Comment: Select them all and process with PHP.

Comment: @JohnConde thanks john, sometimes you just need to know what to input into the google

Comment: Use a LIMIT in your SELECT statement

Comment: For such a small data set, I would go with @DerekS's solution.

Comment: @Strawberry scalability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ORDER BY to sort your results as well as LIMIT to declare limitations.

```
SELECT * FROM teachers ORDER BY primary_key LIMIT 10
```

To start at a certain point (ie. 11 and show only 10) you can add this:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers ORDER BY primary_key LIMIT 11,10
```

You can then create a PHP script to generate the value for the limit offset... so 21,10, 31,10, etc.

[MySQL Select Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT

```
SELECT * FROM teachers LIMIT 0, 10;

SELECT * FROM teachers LIMIT 10, 10;
```

The first number is where to start, and the second is how many results you want to get.

I have an implementation of this where I have a php script to get the page number and the first number is a variable $limit_start. It gets the page number from a post or get.

```
$limit_start = ($this->page - 1) * 10;

$query = 'SELECT * FROM teachers LIMIT '.$limit_start.', 10';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this using an offset limit within your query. Page 1 would be:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers limit 0,10
```

page 2:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers limit 10,10
```

page 3:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers limit 20,10
```

... and so on. First value is the offset and the second value is the number of rows to retrieve.